# Can not increment global variable from function in python

Tags: python

From this code:

```
COUNT = 0

def increment():
    COUNT = COUNT + 1

increment()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    increment()
  File "test.py", line 4, in increment
    COUNT = COUNT+1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'COUNT' referenced before assignment
```

Why? How can I increment the global variable `COUNT` from inside the function?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them Looks like Python won't change the global value unless you specify that it's what you want to do.

Comment: The use of `global` among beginners is usually a sign of bad design.

Comment: without using `global` you can't modify the value of a global variable inside a function, you can only use it's value inside the function. But if you want to assign a new value to it then you've to use the `global` keyword first.

Answer (score 130):

Use a `global` statement, like so:

```
COUNT = 0

def increment():
    global COUNT
    COUNT = COUNT+1

increment()
```

Global variables can be accessed without using `global`, but the statement is required in order to change the value of the global variable.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This one is better as I have tried already using "count += 1" alone but wasn't working. This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This no longer works. Old solution.

Answer (score 35):

This is because globals don't bleed into the scope of the function. Use the `global` statement to force this for assignment:

```
>>> COUNT = 0
>>> def increment():
...     global COUNT
...     COUNT += 1
... 
>>> increment()
>>> print(COUNT)
1
```

Note that using globals is a really bad idea - it makes code hard to read, and hard to use. Instead, return a value from your function (using `return`) and use that to do something. If the same data needs to be accessible from a range of functions, consider making a class.

It's also worth noting that `CAPITALS` is generally reserved for constants, so it's a bad idea to name global variables like this. For normal variables, `lowercase_with_underscores` is preferred.