# How can a name be "unbound" in Python? What code can cause an `UnboundLocalError`?

Tags: python, variables, namespaces

I read the following [in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

> When a name is not found at all, a `NameError` exception is raised. If the current scope is a function scope, and the name refers to a local variable that has not yet been bound to a value at the point where the name is used, an `UnboundLocalError` exception is raised. `UnboundLocalError` is a subclass of `NameError`.
> ...
> Python lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere within a code block.

I don't understand how this works. If there are no declarations, then when does `UnboundLocalError` get raised? How can the variable "not yet be bound" when it is encountered?

---

<sub>See also [UnboundLocalError trying to use a variable (supposed to be global) that is (re)assigned (even after first use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357) for a common problem where a variable expected to be global, is local instead. This question is focused on cases where the programmer expects the variable to be local.</sub>

Comment: For duplicate closers: **Please do not** use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367760/ to close questions where OP had a logic error preventing a local from being assigned in some situations. Use this one instead (or if you find something better, please show me in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434/python-canon-discussion). The other one has a poor setup; understanding the problem is complicated by the issue of trying to read a file twice (hence me closing it with two very different duplicates).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can *refer* to a name without having assigned to it:

```
>>> foobar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foobar' is not defined
```

Here `foobar` is being referred to, but was never assigned to. This raises a `NameError` because the name was never bound.

More subtly, here assignment is not happening because the line that does is never run:

```
>>> def foo():
...     if False:
...         spam = 'eggs'
...     print(spam)
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'spam' referenced before assignment
```

Because `spam = 'eggs'` is never executed, `print(spam)` raises an `UnboundLocalError`.

Note that nowhere in Python is a name ever *declared*. You bind or don't bind, declaration is not part of the language.

Instead, *binding* is used to determine the scope of a name; binding operations include assignment, names used for a `for` loop, function parameters, import statements, name to hold a caught exception in an `except` clause, and the name for a context manager in a `with` statement.

If a name is bound in a scope (such as in a function) then it is a local name, unless you use a `global` statement (or a `nonlocal` statement in Python 3) to explicitly mark the name as a global (or a closure) instead.

So the following is an error:

```
>>> foo = None
>>> def bar():
...     if False:
...         foo = 'spam'
...     print(foo)
... 
>>> bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in bar
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

because `foo` is being bound *somewhere* in the `bar` function scope. But if you mark `foo` as a global, the function works:

```
>>> foo = None
>>> def bar():
...     global foo
...     if False:
...         foo = 'spam'
...     print(foo)
... 
>>> bar()
None
```

because now the Python compiler knows you wanted `foo` to be a global instead.

This is all documented in the [*Naming and Binding* section](https://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) of the Python reference documentation.

Comment: Very nice example, thanks! Does it mean that a specified block bindings are created before the code of this block is starting to execute?

Comment: @Dmitrii: the compiler stores local names with the code block; this so the byte code can use the correct opcodes to load global names vs. local names vs. closures.

Comment: Python decides whether a variable is local while compiling to byte code. If it's ever assigned to, it's local (unless there is a `global` or `nonlocal` declaration for it).

Comment: @kindall: not just assignment; importing, function parameters, `for` loop targets, `except` and `with` clause `as` targets all bind names.

Comment: You are technically correct... the best kind of correct. (In my mind all those are assignments, though.)

Comment: @kindall: The [reference manual](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) calls it binding, then names assignment as an action that binds. Best to stick to the official terminology when writing answers on SO. :-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand you. Where can I read about python bytecode instruction and how to compile sources to bytecode?

Comment: "This is all documented in the Naming and Binding section of the Python reference documentation." Yes, but... *that's where OP was quoting from*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Not exactly. They quoted from the 'Resolution of names', but they should also read the important 'Binding of names' section before it.

Answer (score 4):

One more place is when the variable is declared in global scope and if it is used in function scope, it should specifically refer as global otherwise UnboundLocalError occurs. Following is the example:

```
var = 123
def myfunc():
    var = var + 1
    print var

myfunc()
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: I had edited this, but then rolled it back because I think I changed the spirit of it too much. Instead, I integrated the changes I wanted to make into a completely new answer.

Answer (score 2):

`UnboundLocalError` is a special kind of `NameError`, that specifically refers to local variables. The same kinds of logical problems that cause `NameError`s in code outside of functions, can cause `UnboundLocalError` inside them.

Commonly, the problem occurs when trying to write conditional logic that doesn't have any fallback:

```
import random

def example_if():
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        result = 1
    return result

print(example_if())
```

This will fail whenever the condition isn't satisfied, because in that case there wasn't anything assigned to `result`, so there's no way to use it. It's important to understand here that **there are no "default" values** for variables, and that assigning `None` to something is **not the same** as deleting the name with `del`. You would need to explicitly define a fallback, for example:

```
def example_if():
    result = 1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 0
    return result
```

(This error could also be a symptom of a logical error with indentation: check whether the code using the variable is *also* supposed to be inside the `if` block.)

A sneaky variation on this is a loop that is supposed to assign the value, but runs zero times:

```
def example_for():
    for i in range(0): # this loop will not be entered
        result = 1 # therefore this assignment will not happen
    return result

print(example_for()))
```

In more practical examples, a `for` loop might fail to run because it is iterating over results from a searching operation (e.g. another loop) that didn't find anything, or because it is iterating over a [file that was already read](/q/3906137).

`UnboundLocalError` can also occur when trying to modify a variable that wasn't already assigned:

```
def example_increment():
    result += 1

example_increment()
```

This happens because the existing value needs to be looked up before it can be modified, but there is nothing to look up.

Either way, the error will happen **even if** there is a `result` in the global scope, because Python [decided ahead of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357) to treat the variable as local. To solve this, [use the `global` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379) **in addition to** giving the initial global value. It must be used in **each** function that wants to modify the global. (`global` in global scope has **no effect**.)

```
import random

result = 1

def example_increment():
    global result
    result += 1

def example_if():
    global result
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        result = 1
    return result

example_increment() # result becomes 2
print(example_if()) # may or may not reset to 1
```

Using `global` is [not necessary if the value is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120). However, a global cannot be used to set an initial value for a local of the same name:

```
result = 1

def does_not_work():
    result = result # trying to set a "default" value for a local
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        result = 2
    return result
```

This can't work either way. As is, `UnboundLocalError` will occur. If `global result` is added to the function, then `result = result` will have no effect, and the function will potentially modify the global (not wanted here). For these cases, the workaround is to simply **use a different name** for the local.