# UnboundLocalError is seen after few clean runs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see unboundlocalerror at random times. Could you please point me how to fix this?

```
def find_switch_and_port_cis(wwn):
    with open('zones_list.txt') as fin:
        for line in islice(dropwhile(lambda L: wwn not in L, fin), 1, 15, 1):
            if 'connected interface' in line:
                interface = re.findall(':(\S+)', line)
            elif 'switch name' in line:
                switch_name = re.findall(':(\S+)', line)
        print(wwn, ' is connected to interface:' , interface[0], ' on switch:', switch_name[0])

find_switch_and_port_cis(wwn)
```

The code gives the expect output:

```
50:01:43:80:01:1b:42:f6  is connected to interface: fc2/17  on switch: c3-cs9513-02
```

After few runs but after few runs it throws:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'interface' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: If your `for` loop has 0 iterations or you never enter the `if` clause, you cannot print the value of `interface` variable because it has never been declared.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" after an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367760/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-after-an-if-sta)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a name be "unbound" in Python? What code can cause an \`UnboundLocalError\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101836/how-can-a-name-be-unbound-in-python-what-code-can-cause-an-unboundlocalerror)