# NameError: name 'is_zero' is not defined

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong here?

```
money = 2.01
str_money = str(money)
last_digit = str_money[-1]
if last_digit == "0":
    is_zero = True
print(is_zero)
```

This is the error code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robin Groot\PycharmProjects\huiswerk\TestLes2.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(is_zero)
NameError: name 'is_zero' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

EDIT: I found the problem, At the moment the if statement is not true it breaks at print because there is no value for is_zero you can solve this by adding an else statement or putting the print into the if statement.

Comment: Indeed, since your condition is false (there is no trailing 0 in your number), `is_zero`is not defined. You may add `is_zero = false` at the begining of your code

Comment: or without `if`: `is_zero = last_digit == "0"` or `is_zero = str_money.endswith("0")`

Comment: When reviewing code, if without else requires extra scrutiny. Does any later code depend on something done in the if? In your case, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" after an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367760/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-after-an-if-sta)

Comment: @wjandrea that question is problematic because of the complex setup: the strange behaviour OP experienced was caused by the intersection of this problem, with trying to read an open file twice in a row. I have improved and established a new canonical (at least for now), for the cases where the variable is expected to be local: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101836.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add else condition or define is_zero = False at the begining.

```
money = 2.01
str_money = str(money)
last_digit = str_money[-1]
if last_digit == "0":
    is_zero = True
else:
    is_zero = False
    
print(is_zero)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked is there a reason I can define variables but not bools in an if statement?

Comment: @JOMOGO Your question doesn't make sense to me. Could you explain what you mean with "defining bools in an if statement"?

Comment: Simpler: `is_zero = last_digit == "0"`

Comment: @wjandrea I seached the internet and could not find a solution like this thank you very much.

Comment: @Robin Not sure what there is to search for. That is just a refactoring hack that you learn over time