# How come my variable is 'referenced before assignment' but isn't when I change the word it is assigned to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question that is sort of a problem.

I am making a crafting program to learn python more but came across a problem; I assign my variables at the start and user them later like you are supposed to, however it came up with an error message 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vSaplings' referenced before assignment'. I tried many different ways of writing it but in the end, all I had to do was change

```
vSaplings
```

to

```
v_Saplings
```

Now there is no error. Why did this need to be done? It's just a character being added.

Code in question:

```
vSaplings = 20
...
elif reqO == "Twigs":
        print("This requires at least 1 sapling.")
        if vSaplings > 0:
            amountSaplings = input("How many saplings would you like to use to craft twigs? 1 sapling = 3 twigs.")
```

This gets the error. Changing 'vSaplings' to 'v_Saplings' removes the error. Why?

Thank you.

EDIT: I now understand that it actually needs to be a global variable. Just 1 more question then, do I need to make my variables global in every single function I create? That seems like it would take up a lot of space.

Comment: `vSaplings` and `v_Saplings` are two different variables.  I think we'll need more context.  Are you saying that you changed *both* instances of that name, or just one or the other?

Comment: Sorry. Yes I changed both and it worked.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vSaplings' referenced before assignment` -> Do you have v_Saplings anywhere else in that file?

Comment: Change them both back, make no other changes. Does it fail again? (I'm predicting it will still work, and the problem was something else / somewhere else)

Comment: possible duplicate of [python UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367760/python-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: Is the code that's accessing `vSaplings` in a function, while the initial definition is at the top level? If so, is some other code in the function assigning to `vSaplings`? That will cause an error, as the local variable hides the global variable. You can fix that with a `global` statement, or using a different name if the conflict is accidental.

Comment: My guess is that you have a *third* place (probably inside a function) where you use that variable name.  Remember that functions that use a variable name that's defined at the global scope must declare their intent to do so by saying `global vSaplings` (in this case).

Comment: Yes I have that variable elsewhere. Blckknght you are right, how do I make it a global variable then?

I tried global vSaplings but then I cannot assign a value to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError trying to use a variable (supposed to be global) that is (re)assigned (even after first use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-trying-to-use-a-variable-supposed-to-be-global-that-is-rea)

Answer (score 0):

You've done something like this:

```
#This will NOT work
foo = 20

def f():
    if foo > 10:
        print 'hello'
    foo = foo + 1
```

This will trigger the Unbound local error.

To work around it, you can do one of a couple of things.  The simplest is something like this:

```
#This is OK
foo = 20

def f():
    global foo
    if foo > 10:
        print 'hello'
    foo = foo + 1
```

However, as a general rule, you should work to [avoid global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).  There are a host of reasons for this, most of which boil down to "it makes the code harder to understand and maintain.  It's easier to reason about self-contained functions, and so you might consider doing something more like this:

```
#Better (in the opinion of this poster)

def f(foo):
    if foo > 10:
        print 'hello'
    return foo + 1
```

Which could then be called from anywhere like this:

```
foo = f(foo)
```