# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-requests

Getting random results from same program

I am making a post call using python requests library. My program works fine sometimes as I expected but gives error  "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment" some other times.

```
def test_fun():
    try:
        response = requests.get(f"{Base_URI}/Calls.json", auth=(AccSid, AccToken))
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')

    assert response.status_code == 200

"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment"
```

Comment: `response` doesn't get set if an exception occurs. In which case you print the "other error occurred" message and then continue normally out of the `except` block. Since the `response = ...` statement didn't execute fully, `response` doesn't exist, so when you try to reference it in the `assert` statement, you get an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment when reading from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367760/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-when-reading-from)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but in case of exception it does not print anything that I have given in the except block. any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Green Cloak Guy said, when an exception occurs, your `response` variable is undefined. This causes the error. To fix this, you can add an `else` statement to your `try`:

```py
def test_fun():
    try:
        response = requests.get(f"{Base_URI}/Calls.json", auth=(AccSid, AccToken))
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
    else:
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

The `else` block is ran when there were no exceptions raised. Note that this is different from `finally`, which always runs *regardless* of whether an error was raised or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raise_for_status()` to raise an exception if the request wasn't successful.

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)

    # raise exception only if the request was unsuccessful
    response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
else:
    # check the exact status and do your stuff.
```

Comment: Pls consider accepting or upvoting the answer so that it is clear for others that your issue is resolved.