# I want to make decimal transformation function

Tags: python

```
def replace_base(x):
    x = x.replace('10', 'A')
    x = x.replace('11', 'B')
    x = x.replace('12', 'C')
    x = x.replace('13', 'D')
    x = x.replace('14', 'E')
    x = x.replace('15', 'F')
    x = x.replace('16', 'G')
    return x

def deci_to_any_list():
    n1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    n = int(n1)
    radix1 = input("Enter a radix: ")
    radix = int(radix1)
    converted_number = []
    if n>0:
        if 2<=radix<=16:
            while int(n/radix) == 0:
                converted_number.append(n % radix)
                converted_number.reverse()
                x = ''.join(str(i) for i in converted_number)
                replace_base(x)
            else:
                converted_number.append(n % radix)
        else:
            print("Wrong input!!")
    else:
        print("Wrong input!!")

    print("%d in base 10 is %d in base %d" % (n1,x,radix1))

deci_to_any_list()
```

Input & error,

```
Enter a number: 61
Enter a radix: 16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LG/기컴프과제2/Number conversion.py", line 33, in <module>
    deci_to_any_list()
  File "C:/Users/LG/기컴프과제2/Number conversion.py", line 31, in deci_to_any_list
    print("%d in base 10 is %d in base %d" % (n1,x,radix1))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to create a decimal transformation function. I posted a question earlier, but you asked me to give you more details, so I'm leaving a question again. I don't know how to fix the error, and I don't know how to make this function. It can make to divide the quotient by the radix base number until the quotient is 0. And, write remainders in reverse order. I want to make this function using the append, reverse,join function,formatting operator(%). At this time, n shall be positive number and radix shall be 2 to 16. The last result is '61 in base 10 is 3D in base 16'.

Comment: All you need to fix your error is: declare `x = ''` before `if n>0:...`.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. I'm inferring you want to know how to fix it, but please be specific and explicit. BTW welcome to SO! Please read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15367760/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `x` only gets defined if `2 <= radix <= 16`, yet regardless, at the bottom you call `print("%d in base 10 is %d in base %d" % (n1,x,radix1))`, which attempts to print out `x` even if it wasn't defined. To fix this, either move your print statement inside the condition `if 2 <= radix <= 16`, or define `x` in your else-statement as well.

Also be careful about your indentation, and note that `replace_base(x)` does not change the value of x unless you do `x = replace_base(x)`.