# Difficulty understanding 'local variable referenced before assignment'

Tags: python

There are a lot of posts with similar questions but even after going through them, I am unable to get the logic behind. Sorry, I have never programmed before. Below are two pieces of code - a recursive function for calculating the factorial. 
This gets an error 'local variable 'f' referenced before assignment' whether I pass 1 or any value.

```
def func(n):
    if n != 1:
        f = n*func(n-1)
    else:        
        return f
```

However, when I change the code to:

```
def func(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:        
        f = n*func(n-1)

    return f
```

there's no error and the program runs. 
In both cases, I have **not** initialized the variable 'f' before assigning and both are local to the function only. Just trying to get my basic concepts cleared. Thanks.

Comment: In the first example where does the value of `f` come from if  `n != 1`?

Comment: Think about what happens in the first example if you go into the `else` branch. In that case, when you `return f` it isn't defined. In the second example, the `if` branch returns, and the `else` branch assigns `f`, so you can never reach `return f` without `f` being defined

Comment: In the second program you have two choices, one that returns with `1` (where `f` is not needed) and in the other one you do assign `f`. A `return` statement immediately terminates the function, so no other variables or statements are checked.

Comment: If n==1, what does your first `func(N)` return? Has `f` been assigned to at that point in the flow of execution?

Comment: Actually, error message is pretty informative. You can add `f = 1` at the start of function, it'll work as well.

Comment: Related: [UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment when reading from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15367760/4518341) - also about a local variable that's undefined under certain conditions.

Comment: This is a result of the poster not understanding how the recursion works, not a misunderstanding of the scope of Python variables.

The accepted answer says:

> Suppose that your passed parameter n won't be equal to 1. The if n != 1 condition would be evaluated to False.

Which is blatantly wrong. If "n won't be equal to 1" then "n != 1" would be evaluated to True, not False. The first bullet point about "no base case" is accurate.

Despite the assignment to f in the same statement, func is evaluated first. n - 1 reduces n repeatedly until reaching 1, where f does not have a value yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Function 1 -

```
def func(n):
    if n != 1:
        f = n*func(n-1)
    else:        
        return f
```

- In the first function, `f` might still be uninitialized ( depending on the input ) when you are returning it. Your first function doesn't have a base case as in the second one.
- Suppose that your passed parameter `n` won't be equal to 1. The `if n != 1` condition would be evaluated to `False`. Then how would `else` statement return `f` when it hasn't been initialsed yet? and hence the error...

---

#### Function 2 -

```
def func(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:        
        f = n*func(n-1)    
    return f
```

- However, in your second function, you will always either be initializing `f` before you return it ( n >= 1 ) or going into an infinite recursion( n < 1 ) . No matter what, you won't be returning it without initializing. So it gives no error.

Hope you understand why the error occurs.

Comment: Just so I get it right - does that mean that the code should ensure that the variable has been assigned some value before it can be used in 'return' ?

Comment: That's right. Initialised would be the correct word, though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this function:

```
def func(n):
    return f
```

It trivially easy to see why this function would give an error since `f` doesn't exist.

In your first function, if `n != 1` evaluates `False`, it will behave like the example function I gave above.

As @Mustafa Aydın commented the error is slightly different than your `UnboundLocalError` but the concept remains.

Comment: When executed, your function `func` will give a `NameError` _not_ `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @MustafaAydın - Thanks. I edited the question to reflect that.