# UnboundLocalError and i dont understand how to fix

Tags: python, python-3.x

this post is going to be super long, but here goes nothing.

I am writing a segment of a program that manages profiles. the profile contains billing and shipping address, and credit card number stuff as well. they import from a generic file, which looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test-0-2-21",
    "size": "",
    "profileGroup": "",
    "billingAddress": {
      "name": "yes sir",
      "email": "yessir@gmail.com",
      "phone": "1111111111",
      "line1": "11 Garden Place",
      "line2": "11",
      "line3": "",
      "postCode": "07960",
      "city": "Chatham",
      "country": "United States",
      "state": "New Jersey"
    },
    "shippingAddress": {
      "name": "yes sir",
      "email": "yessir@gmail.com",
      "phone": "1111111111",
      "line1": "11 Garden Place",
      "line2": "11",
      "line3": "",
      "postCode": "07960",
      "city": "Chatham",
      "country": "United States",
      "state": "New Jersey"
    },
    "paymentDetails": {
      "nameOnCard": "yeet",
      "cardType": "",
      "cardNumber": "1111111111111111",
      "cardExpMonth": "12",
      "cardExpYear": "2023",
      "cardCvv": "321"
    },
    "sameBillingAndShippingAddress": true,
    "onlyCheckoutOnce": false,
    "matchNameOnCardAndAddress": false
  }
]
```

my code looks like this:

```
import os
import json

def profile_list():
    parent_dir = os.getcwd()
    created_dir = r"\Profiles"
    script_dir = parent_dir + created_dir
    checklist_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "Profiles.txt")

    try:
        checklist_file = open(checklist_path, "r")
        profile_list = checklist_file.read()
        print(profile_list)
        user_input()
    except IndexError:
        print("err")

def user_input():

    def edit_handler():
        profile_editor()
    def exec_handler():
        print("yay 2")

    def import_handler():
        importer()

    print("what do you want to do?")
    question = input(" \n type [1] to view/edit/create profiles, \n type [2] to execute a profile, \n "
                     "type [3] to import/export profiles. \n \n $")

    handlers = {
        '1': edit_handler,
        '2': exec_handler,
        '3': import_handler
    }

    if question in handlers:
        handlers[question]()
    else:
        print("Unknown choice", question)

def viewer():
    parent_dir = os.getcwd()
    created_dir = r"\Profiles"
    script_dir = parent_dir + created_dir
    profiles_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "Profiles.txt")
    try:
        with open(profiles_path, "r") as profile_file:
            profile_list = profile_file.read()
        print(profile_list)
    except IndexError:
        print("err")
    opening_question = input("please type the name of the profile you would like to enter. (case sensitive) \n \n $")

    file_name = opening_question
    file_extension = ".txt"
    file_dir = file_name + file_extension

    with open(profiles_path, 'r'):
        if opening_question in profile_list:
            with open(file_dir) as open_file:
                file_content = json.load(open_file)
                json_dump = json.dumps(file_content, indent=2)
            print(json_dump)
        else:
            print("Unknown choice", opening_question)

def profile_editor():

    def view_handler():
        viewer()
    def edit_handler():
        print("yay 2")

    def create_handler():
        print("to profile file")

    print("what do you want to do?")
    question = input(" \n type [1] to view a profile, \n type [2] to edit a profile, \n "
                     "type [3] to create/delete profiles. \n \n $")

    handlers = {
        '1': view_handler,
        '2': edit_handler,
        '3': create_handler
    }

    if question in handlers:
        handlers[question]()
    else:
        print("Unknown choice", question)

def importer():

    def setup():
        question = input("please enter the directory of the .json file you want to import. \n "
                         "(this is the exact system directory, for example, [C:\<user_folders>\Downloads])\n "
                         "DO NOT INCLUDE THE FILE IN THIS DIRECTORY \n \n $")
        question2 = input("please enter the name of the file, including the .json extension. (for example, "
                          "[aycd.json])\n \n $")
        file_name = "\\" + question2
        file_name.strip()
        directory = question + file_name
        directory = directory.strip()

        def import_confirmation():
            import_conformation = input("type [y] to import, type [n] to cancel. \n \n $")
            if import_conformation == "y":
                print("transferring")
                convert()
            elif import_conformation == "n":
                print("canceling...")
                user_input()
            else:
                print("unknown answer:", import_conformation)


        profile_name = [2]


        with open(directory, 'r') as importing_file:
            for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                line = line.strip()
                if position in profile_name:
                    print("is this the name of the correct profile?")
                    print("------------------------------------------")
                    print(line)
                    print("------------------------------------------")
                    import_hotswap = open("import_hotswap.txt", "w")
                    import_hotswap.write(directory)
                    import_hotswap.close()
                    import_confirmation()
                else:
                    pass

    def convert():
        readline_profilename = [2]
        readline_billing_name = [6]
        readline_billing_email = [7]
        readline_billing_phone = [8]
        readline_billing_line1 = [9]
        readline_billing_line2 = [10]
        readline_billing_line3 = [11]
        readline_billing_postcode = [12]
        readline_billing_city = [13]
        readline_billing_country = [14]
        readline_billing_state = [15]
        readline_shipping_name = [18]
        readline_shipping_email = [19]
        readline_shipping_phone = [20]
        readline_shipping_line1 = [21]
        readline_shipping_line2 = [22]
        readline_shipping_line3 = [23]
        readline_shipping_postcode = [24]
        readline_shipping_city = [25]
        readline_shipping_country = [26]
        readline_shipping_state = [27]
        readline_card_name = [30]
        readline_card_type = [31]
        readline_card_number = [32]
        readline_card_expmonth = [33]
        readline_card_expyear = [34]
        readline_card_ccv = [35]
        readline_samebillingandshippingadress = [37]
        readline_onlycheckoutonce = [38]
        readline_matchnameoncardadress = [39]

        profile_name_question = input("what do you want to call this profile? (do not include the extension)\n \n $")

        parent_dir = os.getcwd()
        created_dir = r"\Profiles"
        script_dir = parent_dir + created_dir
        profiles_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "Profiles.txt")
        new_profile = profile_name_question + ".txt"
        new_profile = new_profile.strip()
        new_profile_path = os.path.join(script_dir, new_profile)
        import_hotswap = open("import_hotswap.txt", "r")
        importing_file_path = import_hotswap.read()
        import_hotswap.close()

        try:
            with open(profiles_path, "a") as profile_file:
                profile_file.write(profile_name_question + "\n")
                profile_file.close()
            with open(profiles_path, "r") as profile_file:
                profile_list = profile_file.read()
                print(profile_list)
                profile_file.close()
        except IndexError:
            print("err")

        try:
            with open(importing_file_path, "r") as importing_file:
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_name:
                        billing_name = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_email:
                        billing_email = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_phone:
                        billing_phone = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_line1:
                        billing_line1 = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_line2:
                        billing_line2 = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_line3:
                        billing_line3 = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_postcode:
                        billing_postcode = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_city:
                        billing_city = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_country:
                        billing_country = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_state:
                        billing_state = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_name:
                        shipping_name = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_email:
                        shipping_email = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_phone:
                        shipping_phone = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_line1:
                        shipping_line1 = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_line2:
                        shipping_line2 = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_line3:
                        shipping_line3 = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_postcode:
                        shipping_postcode = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_city:
                        shipping_city = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_country:
                        shipping_country = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_shipping_state:
                        shipping_state = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_card_name:
                        card_name = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_card_type:
                        card_type = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_card_number:
                        card_number = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_card_expmonth:
                        card_expmonth = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_card_expyear:
                        card_expyear = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_card_ccv:
                        card_ccv = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_samebillingandshippingadress:
                        samebillingandshippingadress = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_onlycheckoutonce:
                        onlycheckoutonce = line
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_matchnameoncardadress:
                        matchnameoncardadress = line


            with open(new_profile_path, "a") as new_profile:
                new_profile.write(profile_name_question + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_name + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_email + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_phone + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_line1 + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_line2 + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_line3 + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_postcode + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_city + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_country + "\n")
                new_profile.write(billing_state + "\n")
                new_profile.close()
                if samebillingandshippingadress == '"sameBillingAndShippingAddress": false,"':
                    new_profile = open(new_profile_path, "a")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_name + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_email + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_phone + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_line1 + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_line2 + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_line3 + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_postcode + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_city + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_country + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(shipping_state + "\n")
                    new_profile.close()
                elif samebillingandshippingadress == '"sameBillingAndShippingAddress": true,':
                    pass
                else:
                    print("error reading file: same billing and shipping adress is unclear. check importing file. "
                          "continuing anyway")
                if matchnameoncardadress == '"matchNameOnCardAndAddress": true':
                    new_profile = open(new_profile_path, "a")
                    new_profile.write("card name:", billing_name + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_type + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_number + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_expmonth + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_expyear + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_ccv + "\n")
                    new_profile.close()
                elif matchnameoncardadress == '"matchNameOnCardAndAddress": false':
                    new_profile = open(new_profile_path, "a")
                    new_profile.write(card_name + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_type + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_number + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_expmonth + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_expyear + "\n")
                    new_profile.write(card_ccv + "\n")
                    new_profile.close()
                else:
                    print("error reading file: match name on card and adress is unclear. check importing file. "
                          "continuing anyway")
        except IndexError:
            print("there was an error somewhere. "
                  "please check that your file is correctly formatted and has all 42 lines.")
    setup()
```

i when running, i get an error that looks like this:

```
File "C:\Users\nicho\Documents\Python stuff\PLTNM\profile_manager.py", line 316, in convert
    new_profile.write(billing_email)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'billing_email' referenced before assignment
```

I've found other posts similar to this one, and they say to use `global` or `nonlocal` to help, but none of their examples are similar enough to try to implement the answers. and by just following context, i define billing_email in line 202, and use it in line 316. could someone explain why exactly it would do this? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. That line from the traceback doesn't appear in your code. Please provide a [mre] with less code. That said, I bet this is a duplicate: [“UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment” after an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15367760/4518341). BTW, check out [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Just as a side note, I really hope you aren't storing real user credit card details in a plaintext file.

Comment: if position in readline_billing_email:
                        billing_email = line #202 line (can you please print output of this just to debug what you are getting ). what "if position not in readline_billing_email" what happens than ?

Comment: @wjandrea the line from the traceback is there. you just need to scroll down. should look like this: `new_profile.write(billing_email + "\n")`

Comment: @NickT I saw that, but the traceback says `new_profile.write(billing_email)`, without the `+ "\n"`. That could indicate that you're accidentally running a different version of the script. If you provide a [mre], we can eliminate that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can't iterate through a file object multiple times unless you seek back to the beginning before each loop. When you iterate through a file object, you start from where the last read left off; if that was a complete iteration, you start from the end, so there's nothing left to read.

So only the first

```
for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
```

loop is processing the file. The rest of them don't iterate at all, so none of them assign their variables.

You should have just one loop, like this:

```
                for position, line in enumerate(importing_file):
                    line = line.strip()
                    if position in readline_billing_name:
                        billing_name = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_email:
                        billing_email = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_phone:
                        billing_phone = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_line1:
                        billing_line1 = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_line2:
                        billing_line2 = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_line3:
                        billing_line3 = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_postcode:
                        billing_postcode = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_city:
                        billing_city = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_country:
                        billing_country = line
                    elif position in readline_billing_state:
                        billing_state = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_name:
                        shipping_name = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_email:
                        shipping_email = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_phone:
                        shipping_phone = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_line1:
                        shipping_line1 = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_line2:
                        shipping_line2 = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_line3:
                        shipping_line3 = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_postcode:
                        shipping_postcode = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_city:
                        shipping_city = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_country:
                        shipping_country = line
                    elif position in readline_shipping_state:
                        shipping_state = line
                    elif position in readline_card_name:
                        card_name = line
                    elif position in readline_card_type:
                        card_type = line
                    elif position in readline_card_number:
                        card_number = line
                    elif position in readline_card_expmonth:
                        card_expmonth = line
                    elif position in readline_card_expyear:
                        card_expyear = line
                    elif position in readline_card_ccv:
                        card_ccv = line
                    elif position in readline_samebillingandshippingadress:
                        samebillingandshippingadress = line
                    elif position in readline_onlycheckoutonce:
                        onlycheckoutonce = line
                    elif position in readline_matchnameoncardadress:
                        matchnameoncardadress = line
```