# What is the exact process in evaluating assignment statements referencing global variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, variable-assignment

If the following program,`test.py` is run with python3:

```py
x = 2

def func1():
    x = 3
    print(x)

def func2():
    x = x + 1
    print(x)

func1()
func2()
```

It generates the following output:

```
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    func2()
  File "test.py", line 8, in func2
    x = x + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

`func1` operates exactly as I would expect. A local variable `x` is created, assigned the value `3` and printed out.

`func2` isn't behaving how I would expect. Based on the expression evaluation order shown here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the arithmetic order of their suffixes:
>
> ...
>
> `expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2`

I would expect in `func2`, the statement `x = x + 1` would first evaluate the right hand side, obtain the value of `x` as being `2` from the global scope, evaluate the expression `x + 1` to be `3`, and assign that value to a local variable `x`. Finally printing out `3`.

Please explain why this isn't how the code is behaving. I have seen other seemingly relevant questions here:

- [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)
- [Can not increment global variable from function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506973/can-not-increment-global-variable-from-function-in-python)

But they simply mention how I should be using the `global` keyword, they don't really explain the actual evaluation order by Python.

Comment: This is not a question of evaluation order. Python uses a simple rule: if you assign to a variable name anywhere in a function, then it is considered local to this function, unless declared global.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for linking to [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use). [Charlie Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370380/17120019) about the scan being done in two stages, lexing and parsing answers what I was confused about.