# Creating quiz game with function does not update the global score variable

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I'm trying to code a quiz game, which every time you get a correct answer adds 1 point; at the end of the game the program prints out the number of points. The thing is, I'm trying to code it by using a function.

```
def qea(x, y, z):
    if x == y:
        print("Correct!")
        z += 1
    else:
        print('Wrong!')

points = 0

question1 = input("Who is the president of USA?: ").upper()
answer1 = "JOE BIDEN"
qea(question1, answer1, points)

question1 = input("Alexander...: ").upper()
answer1 = "THE GREAT"
qea(question1, answer1, points)

print(points)
```

Why is the program output always 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not increment global variable from function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506973/can-not-increment-global-variable-from-function-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You should return the new value and assign it back to `points`:

```py
def qea(x, y, z):
    if x == y:
        print("Correct!")
        z += 1
    else:
        print('Wrong!')
    return z

points = 0

question1 = input("Who is the president of USA?: ").upper()
answer1 = "JOE BIDEN"
points = qea(question1, answer1, points)

question1 = input("Alexander...: ").upper()
answer1 = "THE GREAT"
points = qea(question1, answer1, points)

print(points)
```

Comment: This one worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that the function is changing `z`, not `points`. If you change the order of your code, and also delete your `z` prop, then it should work.

```py
points = 0

def qea(x, y):
    if x == y:
        print("Correct!")
        points += 1
    else:
        print('Wrong!')

question1 = input("Who is the president of USA?: ").upper()
answer1 = "JOE BIDEN"
qea(question1, answer1)

question1 = input("Alexander...: ").upper()
answer1 = "THE GREAT"
qea(question1, answer1)

print(points)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, the output is:

TypeError: qea() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'

Comment: @Astrologo It seems like someone edited my response. It should be working now. Sorry!